# How to enable a command buttons

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton

I'mm using 3 command buttons in my java swing program such as read, stop and exit.
 if I click read button, all 3 buttons are not in enable state until reading the file.
I need your help to make those buttons to enable and stop the reading action if i click stop button.

Comment: put setEnabled(false) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 3):

Mind you, Swing is a monothreaded framework built on top of a multithreaded platform.
As a consequence, when you perform a long running task, you should not use the [Swing EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).

Hopefully, Swing already includes all what is needed to perform such a long running job.

1. create a separate thread that will read your file
2. once it is done, invoke [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to have UI refreshed according to your file content.

Answer (score 1):

For Read Button ,for ex set action like this :

```
private void ReadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       ReadButton.setEnabled(false);
       StopButton.setEnabled(false);
       ExitButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

For  stop Button : set action like this :

```
private void StopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       ReadButton.setEnabled(true);
       StopButton.setEnabled(true);
       ExitButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

To stop reading action : 
make the reading action as a thread (in Read Button), and then in (Stop Button) stop this thread

for ex:

```
class Read extends Thread {

    public void run() {
    //////////////Read action
}
}
```

- Read read = new Read();
- then in *ReadButtonActionPerformed* :**read.start();**
- in *StopButtonActionPerformed*:  **read.stop();**

Answer (score 1):

Use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for doing that. While you are reading the file make the button disabled and after finishing the file make the buttons enable. A simple example shows how this works.

[image: Swing Worker Example to Enable Disable Buttons]  [image: Before Calculation]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MyProgressBarTest {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JProgressBar progressBar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyProgressBarTest obj = new MyProgressBarTest();
            obj.createGUI();
        }
    });
    }

    public void createGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton button = new JButton("Progress");

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                MyCustomProgressBarDialog progressBarObj = new MyCustomProgressBarDialog(progressBar, frame);
                progressBarObj.createProgressUI();

                MyActionPerformer actionObj = new MyActionPerformer(progressBar, progressBarObj, button);
                actionObj.execute();

            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyActionPerformer extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {

    JProgressBar fProgressBar;
    MyCustomProgressBarDialog progressDialog;
    JButton button;

    public MyActionPerformer(JProgressBar progressBar, MyCustomProgressBarDialog progressDialog, JButton button) {
        this.fProgressBar = progressBar;
        this.fProgressBar.setVisible(true);
        this.fProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.button = button;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;

        this.button.setEnabled(false);
    }

    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {

        calculateResult();
        return "Finished";
    }

    protected void done() {
        fProgressBar.setVisible(false);
        this.progressDialog.setVisible(false);
        this.button.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void calculateResult() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Progress Bar: " + i);
        }
    }
}

class MyCustomProgressBarDialog extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JFrame motherFrame;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("loading.. ");
    private JButton button;

    public MyCustomProgressBarDialog(JProgressBar progressBar, JFrame frame) {

        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.motherFrame = frame;
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void createProgressUI() {
        add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(50, 40);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(motherFrame);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MyActionPerformer class extends `SwingWorker` which has `done` and `doInBackGround`. In `doInBackGround` method read the file and after finishing it make the buttons enable in the `done` method. I am invoking a method called `calculate` when the `JButton` is clicked.